# Jsonlint states the string is valid JSON, but ajax fails

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I have the following in javascript:

```
        $('#tags').on("change", function (d) {
            var x = JSON.stringify($('#tags').val());
            var y = '{ "tags": "' + $('#tags').val() + '" }';
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "ModuleDesigner.aspx/SaveTags",
                type: "POST",
                data: y,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
```

x = ["Boilers","Chillers"]

y = { "tags": "Boilers,Chillers" }

JSONLint declares them both as valid JSON, but only when I set data to y does my SaveTags WebMethod run. (I find this difficult to debug because it fails silently when I change data to x)

I would prefer to pass through the data as defined by x. Is there a way to do this? And why does it fail if this is supposedly valid JSON?

I have added the error routine. And when I pass x, I get the error:

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding success and error callback functions to see if the arguments passed back reveal anything?

Comment: Just edited the question. I get an error referring to dictionary. I need to investigate this. It's just a simple array of strings.

Comment: x is correct JSON and is returning exactly what you asked it to.  $('#tags').val() will return an array of strings.  json serialization for an array is []. and duplicate id's are incorrect html